# Firefox Compile Simple Load Script - browser.xul

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, onload

I'm trying to add a script tag to every dom page through privileged chrome, so far i'm able to get the first pageload of a tab, but after that, the script does nothing, I'm using Firefox Nightly 44.0. What am i doing wrong???

Documents I'm following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

mozilla-central/browser/base/content/browser.xul (line: 74)

`<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://browser/content/yyy/x.js" />`

chrome://browser/content/yyy/x.js

```
var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
        if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
        var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
        // test desired conditions and do something
        // if (doc.nodeName != "#document") return; // only documents
        // if (win != win.top) return; //only top window.
        // if (win.frameElement) return; // skip iframes/frames
        alert("page is loaded \n" +doc.location.href);
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);
```

mozilla-central/browser/base/jar.mn

```
content/browser/yyy/x.js            (content/yyy/x.js)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `loadFrameScript` with argument of true to listen to future pages. Here are examples: https://github.com/mdn/e10s-example-addons/tree/master/run-script-in-all-pages

```
globalMM.loadFrameScript("chrome://modify-all-pages/content/frame-script.js", true);
```

This is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFrameScriptLoader#loadFrameScript%28%29

To stop it from loading in new tabs, then you have to use `removeDelayedFrameScript`

That github link also shows an example of how to do it with addon-sdk content-scripts.

Comment: Thank you!!! for the example, I'm going to accept your answer.. Thank you! Thank YOU!

Comment: Cool @Null :) but if you want to go with go with content script method you can either use addon sdk or from non-sdk you can use execute in sandbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox#Executing_in_current_tab_scope

Comment: I'll look into that as well, the examples look like what i needed, but i'll see what i come up with.

Comment: So i got the browser to load, even without the sandbox (which i have no clue how that works),  but I've been using the add-on sdk, but are you saying i can add globalMM.loadFrameScript("chrome://modify-all-pages/content/frame-script.js", true);  to the content script? i thought i had to add that to the add-on script?

Comment: @null if you're using addon sdk you shouldnt message with frame scripts and message manager. Sdk was created to abstract this stuff away.

Comment: okay, yep, i was using a bugged library, so sdk does work how i need it to. thanks!